# CS:GO Weapon inspection

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm just wondering how to get the camera so far away when inspecting a weapon:

[image]

Comment: There are also a few console commands to change the way you view the weapon:

 viewmodel_fov 54 To 68 (already mentioned),

 viewmodel_offset_x -2 To 2.5,

 viewmodel_offset_y -2 To 2,

 viewmodel_offset_z -2 To 2,

 cl_righthand 0 Or 1.

Answer (score 2):

That's actually a setting in game related to where you want to draw viewmodels.

If you click on **Game Options**, scroll down to **Item Options**, and mouse over the **Viewmodel Position**, you get three choices, *Desktop*, *Couch* and *Classic*.

[image]

Each puts the viewmodel in a different place, making inspecting the weapons a little different. The differences between each setting:

- Classic
  [image: classic]
- Desktop
  [image: desktop]
- Couch
  [image: couch]

To get a camera view from far away, you'll want to have the **Classic** option selected. From what your picture looks like, you have it on Desktop, you'll want to switch to Classic viewmodels.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change that, the problem is that it also changes if you are playing and not only if you inspect a weapon.

To get the weapon a bit away from your body, you have to change the viewmodel field of view.

There is a easy possibility and a advanced. The easy one is easy and the advanced one is more configurable.

### Easy Method

In the option menu you have the possibility to change the **viewmodel position** under the section **item options** in the menu **game settings**. You have three options to choose from. Classic, Desktop and Couch.

I also think that there are other things are changing to get the look of for example the classic.

It is not very configurable and the weapon is also not that far away as you maybe want. That is the reason why I would suggest you the...

### Advanced Method

To be able to finish the advenced method, you have to activate the **developer console**! You find that option also in the game settings menu. Take a look into the key bindings and check out what is your key to open the console.

After you have done that open the console and use the command:

```
viewmodel_fov [n]
```

I have two pictures with a fov of 54 and 68...

[image: 54]
   <sub>fov of 54</sub>

[image: 68]
   <sub>fov of 68</sub>

It is possible to choose a number between 54 and 68. It depends on how far you want the weapon away. It is also useful to change the fov to see more in the game.